# Oracle: Can I tell programmatically if a procedure contains a commit?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I tell programmatically if a stored procedure has a commit?  In an ideal world this could be detected transitively if one procedure calls another that executes a commit.

I don't need to know if the commit will be executed (since that might be in some conditional logic), just that commit is invoked.

For example, in this snippet I would like to know that p1 calls commit, p2 never calls commit, and p3 calls commit via p1.

```
create or replace procedure p1 as
begin
    insert into foo values(99);
    commit;
end;

create or replace procedure p2 as
begin
    insert into foo values(99);
end;

create or replace procedure p3 as
begin
    p1;
end;
```

Comment: You can look at `dba_dependencies` to get the call stack (`p3` calls `p1`).  The simplest approach to finding out if a procedure contains a commit would be to search `dba_source` for the string "commit".  You could enhance that to deal with comments or, if your developers are really twisted, identifiers that include "commit" in the name.

Comment: Great suggestions Justin.  and I'll leave people who code "execute immediate 'c'||'o'||'m'||'m'||'i'||'t'" to their own devices!

Comment: Of course, developers might intentionally or unintentionally be doing something else that causes a transaction to commit.  Using `execute immediate` to do any sort of DDL, for example, or calling certain APIs (the `dbms_scheduler` package, for example, frequently does implicit commits).  If you're trying to track that, you've got a much bigger problem.

Comment: You might find it useful to prevent the commit from happening in the first place - you can issue `ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE` to cause it to fail with an error if it tries to commit.

Answer (score 3):

I have a package procedure I wrote for this.  I'll paste the code below.

To use it, just call "start_no_commit_section" with a name you give.  Then, later, call "end_no_commit_section" with the same name.  If a commit (or rollback) has been issued, the call to "end_no_commit_section" will raise an error.

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell you *where* the commit happened.  If I have a lot of code to look through, I'll generally run DBMS_HPROF on my code and then look for a commit in the HPROF results (which will tell me the exact line number).

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXCUST_TRANSACTION_UTIL AS
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  -- See package spec for comments
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  TYPE no_commit_section_t IS RECORD (local_transaction_id VARCHAR2 (200));

  TYPE no_commit_sections_tab IS TABLE OF no_commit_section_t
                                   INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (80);

  g_no_commit_sections   no_commit_sections_tab;

  PROCEDURE start_no_commit_section (p_section_name VARCHAR2) IS
    l_section   no_commit_section_t;
  BEGIN
    l_section.local_transaction_id                          := DBMS_TRANSACTION.local_transaction_id (create_transaction => TRUE);
    g_no_commit_sections (SUBSTR (p_section_name, 1, 80))   := l_section;
  END start_no_commit_section;


  PROCEDURE end_no_commit_section (p_section_name VARCHAR2) IS
    l_local_transaction_id   VARCHAR2 (200);
  BEGIN
    l_local_transaction_id   := DBMS_TRANSACTION.local_transaction_id (create_transaction => TRUE);

    IF l_local_transaction_id != g_no_commit_sections (SUBSTR (p_section_name, 1, 80)).local_transaction_id THEN
      -- There has been a commit or a rollback in the no-commit section
      raise_application_error(-20001,'A commit or rollback has been detected in "No commit" section ' || p_section_name || '.');
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      -- Caller specified a non-existent commit section
      raise_application_error(-20001,'"No commit" section ' || p_section_name || ' not established.');
  END end_no_commit_section;
END XXCUST_TRANSACTION_UTIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find 99.99% of all (static, explicit, unwrapped) commits by combining `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` with some lexical analysis.

As you said, it's reasonable to exclude pathological cases like `execute immediate 'c'||'o'||'m'||'m'||'i'||'t'`.  But a simple query like `select * from dba_source where lower(text) like '%commit%';` can make mistakes for reasonable code.  Some examples are comments, strings, and substrings of other words.

Tokenizing the code makes it easy to filter out `COMMIT` used in comments, strings, and as substrings.  Looking ahead one token reduces mistakes even more because the [`COMMIT` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4011.htm#i2060233) requires the next "real" token to be one of `WORK`, `COMMENT`, `FORCE`, or `;`.  That eliminates almost all cases of using `COMMIT` as an identifier.  Only a full parser could be 100% accurate but none of the existing PL/SQL parsers are up to the challenge.  (Except for Oracle's parser, which they aren't sharing.)

The code below uses an [open-source tokenizer that I created](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/tokenizer.plsql).

**Install**

```
create or replace type nvarchar2_table is table of nvarchar2(2 char);

create or replace type token is object
(
    type     varchar2(4000),
    value    nclob,
    --Although called "SQL" code and errm, these may also apply to PL/SQL.
    --They would not match the real PL/SQL error messages, but the information
    --should still be helpful to parse broken code.
    sqlcode  number,
    sqlerrm  varchar2(4000)
);

--Use VARRAY because it is guaranteed to maintain order.
create or replace type token_table is varray(2147483647) of token;

--Download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/master/tokenizer.plsql
@tokenizer.plsql
```

**Custom Function**

```
--Return 1 if a COMMIT; is found, else return a 0.
create or replace function has_commit(p_owner varchar2, p_name varchar2, p_type varchar2) return number is
    type varchar2_nt is table of varchar2(4000);
    v_text varchar2_nt := varchar2_nt();
    v_source nclob;
    v_tokens token_table;

    --Return the next concrete token's value, or NULL if there are no more.
    function get_next_concrete_value(p_token_index in number) return nvarchar2 is
    begin
        --Loop through the tokens.
        for i in p_token_index + 1 .. v_tokens.count loop
            --Return it if it's concrete.
            if v_tokens(i).type not in ('whitespace', 'comment', 'EOF') then
                return v_tokens(i).value;
            end if;
        end loop;

        --Return NULL if nothing was found.
        return null;
    end get_next_concrete_value;

begin
    --Get source.
    select text
    bulk collect into v_text
    from all_source
    where owner = p_owner
        and name = p_name
        and type = p_type;

    --Convert source into a single NCLOB.
    for i in 1 .. v_text.count loop
        v_source := v_source || v_text(i);
    end loop;

    --Tokenize the source.
    v_tokens := tokenizer.tokenize(v_source);

    --Look for a COMMIT token followed by either WORK, COMMENT, FORCE, or ;.
    --Return 1 (true) if it's found.
    --http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4011.htm#i2060233
    for v_token_index in 1 .. v_tokens.count loop
        if
        (
            upper(v_tokens(v_token_index).value) = 'COMMIT'
            and 
            upper(get_next_concrete_value(v_token_index))
                in ('WORK', 'COMMENT', 'FORCE', ';')
        ) then
            return 1;
        end if;
    end loop;

    --Not found, return 0.
    return 0;
end has_commit;
/
```

**More Sample Procedures**

In addition to P1, P2, and P3, below are some more unusual syntax examples.

```
--A valid, but unusual way to commit.
create or replace procedure p4 as
begin
    commit work comment 'commiting';
end;
/

--Difficult but reasonable code that does not contain a commit.
create or replace procedure p5 as
    --Good luck parsing this string with a regular expression.
    a_string varchar2(1000) := q'<'
        commit;
    >';

begin
    /* Don't count this!
        commit;
    */
    --Or this
    --commit;

    --Getting a bit ridiculous here...
    select 1 commit into a_string from dual;
end;
/

--Unreasonable code that will incorrectly reports as having a commit. 
create or replace procedure p6 as
    v_number number;
begin
    select 1
    into v_number
    from
    (
        --Naming a variable commit is legal but obviously a bad idea.
        select 1 commit
        from dual
    )
    --Uh-oh... "COMMIT" followed by ";" is bad news.
    where 1 = commit;
end;
/
```

**Test the Procedures and Function**

```
select object_name, has_commit(owner, object_name, object_type) has_commit
from dba_objects
where owner = user
    and object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
    and object_name like 'P_'
order by object_name;

OBJECT_NAME   HAS_COMMIT
-----------   ----------
P1                     1 --Correct
P2                     0 --Correct
P3                     0 --Correct
P4                     1 --Correct
P5                     0 --Correct
P6                     1 --WRONG
```

**Object Hierarchy**

Use a statement like this to create the object hierarchy.

```
--Object hierarchy.
--Creating temporary table for quick performance issues.
create table object_hierarchy as
select dba_objects.owner, dba_objects.object_name, dba_objects.object_type
    ,level object_level
    ,connect_by_root(dba_objects.owner) root_owner
    ,connect_by_root(dba_objects.object_name) root_object_name
    ,connect_by_root(dba_objects.object_type) root_object_type
from dba_objects
left join dba_dependencies
    on dba_objects.owner = dba_dependencies.owner
    and dba_objects.object_name = dba_dependencies.name
    and dba_objects.object_type = dba_dependencies.type
start with (dba_objects.owner, dba_objects.object_name, dba_objects.object_type) in 
(
    select owner, object_name, object_type
    from dba_objects
    where owner = user
        and object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
        and object_name like 'P_'
)
connect by dba_objects.owner = prior referenced_owner
    and dba_objects.object_name = prior referenced_name
    and dba_objects.object_type = prior referenced_type
order siblings by object_name;
```

**Hierarchy with COMMIT status**

```
--Object Hierarchy with HAS_COMMIT per row and per group.
select root_owner, root_object_name, root_object_type, owner, object_name, object_type, object_level,
    max(has_commit) over (partition by root_owner, root_object_name, root_object_type) has_any_commit,
    has_commit
from
(
    --Combine hierarchy with HAS_COMMIT.
    select root_owner, root_object_name, root_object_type, object_level
        ,object_hierarchy.owner, object_hierarchy.object_name, object_hierarchy.object_type
        ,has_commit
    from object_hierarchy
    join
    (
        --Add has_commit
        select owner, object_name, object_type
            --Standard is an exception because it defines the procedure "COMMIT;".
            ,case
                when owner = 'SYS' and object_name = 'STANDARD' then
                    0
                else
                 has_commit(owner, object_name, object_type)
            end has_commit
        from
        (
            select distinct owner, object_name, object_type
            from object_hierarchy
        )
    ) add_has_commit
        on object_hierarchy.owner = add_has_commit.owner
        and object_hierarchy.object_name = add_has_commit.object_name
        and object_hierarchy.object_type = add_has_commit.object_type
) hierarchy_has_commit
order by root_owner, root_object_name, root_object_type, object_level,
    owner, object_name, object_type;
```

**Results Sample**

The results are grouped by the root owner, name, and type.  HAS_ANY_COMMIT indicates whether any procedure in the family has a COMMIT, and HAS_COMMIT indicates whether that specific object has a COMMIT.

```
ROOT_OWNER  ROOT_OBJECT_NAME  ROOT_OBJECT_TYPE  OWNER    OBJECT_NAME   OBJECT_TYPE   OBJECT_LEVEL   HAS_ANY_COMMIT   HAS_COMMIT
JHELLER     P1                PROCEDURE         JHELLER  P1            PROCEDURE     1              1                1
JHELLER     P2                PROCEDURE         JHELLER  P2            PROCEDURE     1              0                0
JHELLER     P3                PROCEDURE         JHELLER  P3            PROCEDURE     1              1                0
JHELLER     P3                PROCEDURE         JHELLER  P1            PROCEDURE     2              1                1
```