# Force rollback in case of an implicit commit

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, commit, rollback

Is there a way in SQL or PLSQL that makes sure that nothing is committed? Since, sometimes a function/procedure is called and the consequences are not known. For example, it can trigger an implicit commit. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Don't write functions that do implicit commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving example in Oracle Database

This is for the SQL statements DML.

```
SQL> set transaction read only;

Transaction set.

SQL> update t set t=14;
update t set t=14
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01456: may not perform insert/delete/update operation inside a READ ONLY
transaction
```

This for calling procedure which has commits in it.

```
  SQL>alter session DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE ;
  SQL>exec procedureHavingCommit(10);
    BEGIN procedureHavingCommit(10); END;

    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00034: cannot COMMIT in current PL/SQL session
    ORA-06512: at "ND210.DRMOP_UTIL", line 332
    ORA-06512: at "ND210.DRMOP_UTIL", line 1664
    ORA-00034: cannot COMMIT in current PL/SQL session
    ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: this one works only if you aren't already in the middle of a transaction. maybe his concern is he wants to be sure that  the procedures he calls inside his transaction (which could be mantained by someone else) won't be modified in future to issue unwanted commits. at least this is a scenario I had to fight with

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that you won't modify anything, the "set transaction read only" is the right answer.

Otherwise: if you are writing some code that calls other procedures wrote by other programmers and your main concern is that these other procedures might issue unwanted commits (or could in future be modified to issue unwanted commits), so you want to catch them before they cause damage, well I have a solution you could find useful that I currently use in my code for exactly this purpose:

let's say your program does this:

```
 procedure MyProcedureThatModifiesData is
 begin
      update mytables....
      SomeOthersProcedure;
      update myothertables ...;
      commit; -- having a commit in a stored procedure 
              -- is a bad idea: i wrote this only to mimick the global         
              -- application behaviour
 end;
```

and you want to be sure that, if the author of the SomeOtherProcedure modifies his procedure inserting a commit inside it, this commit will be blocked and rolled back.

with my solution the code becomes this:

```
 procedure MyProcedureThatModifiesData is
 begin
      pkg_block_unwanted_commits.DisableCommits; // <<!!

      update mytables....
      SomeOthersProcedure;

      update myothertables ...;
      pkg_block_unwanted_commits.ReenableCommits; // <<!!

      commit; -- having a commit in a stored procedure 
              -- is a bad idea: i wrote this only to mimick the global         
              -- application behaviour
end;
```

Let me explain the idea that makes it possible: all you need is a table containing a deferred constraint.
  A deferred constraint is checked only when you issue the "commit": as far as data is not committed it can violate the constraint, but if you try to commit, the whole transaction is rolled back and an oracle error is raised.

Now here is the point: if you INTENTIONALLY insert some data that violates a deferred constraint right at the start of your procedure you will obtain exactly what you are asking for: a rollback instead of a commit.
to re-enable commits all you have to do is to remove the data violating the constraint.

a basic implementation could be this:

```
  procedure MyProcedureThatModifiesData is
  begin
      -- this update "disables" the commits
      update myspecialtable set 
             myfield=unacceptable_value_that_violates_the_constraint;
      update mytables....
      SomeOthersProcedure;
      update myothertables ...;
      -- this update "re-enables" the commits  
      update myspecialtable set 
             myfield=valid_value;
      commit;
  end;
```

a further step to the above basic implementation  is to make "myspecialtable" a global temporary table (kind: preserve rows on commit) so it will only contain the temporary values written during the life of your oracle session and it won't be store permanently in the db. moreover, this way other sessions will be able to write their own data in this special table without interfering with your table.

The complete solution is this one:

```
  create or replace package pkg_block_unwanted_commits is

      -- we will implement these two in order to allow nested calls:
      -- each DisableCommit must be paired with her EnableCommits.
      -- commits will be actually enabled only when each DisableCommit (including 
      -- nested calls) has been closed by her pairing EnableCommit
      procedure DisableCommits;
      procedure ReenableCommits;
  end;
  /
  -- this is the temporary table we will use for the above

  create global temporary table tbl_block_unwanted_commits
  (  
       -- this primary key, along with the "chk_only_one_row" constraint ensures that 
       -- this table can contain only one row
       only_one_row char(1) default 'X' primary key,

       -- it keeps track of the number of "opened" DisableCommits calls:
       -- we can commit only if nest_counter is zero 
       nest_counter number not null
  )
  on commit preserve rows
  /
  -- this one, considering that "only_one_row" is the primary key
  -- ensures we will have only one row in the table (just to be safe)
  alter table tbl_block_unwanted_commits add constraint
       chk_only_one_row check (only_one_row='X') 
  /
  -- this is just to reveal errors in our program if we call EnableCommits without having called DisableCommits 
  -- (mispaired calls)
  alter table tbl_block_unwanted_commits add constraint
       chk_unbalanced_enables check (nest_counter >=0)
  /
  -- this one is the constraint that actually does the trick of blocking commits
  -- we can commit only if whe have active calls to "disablecommits" that have not been paired with corresponding "ReenableCommits"
  alter table tbl_block_unwanted_commits add constraint     
        chk_blocked_commits check (nest_counter = 0) deferrable initially deferred
  /
  create or replace package body  pkg_block_unwanted_commits is

      procedure DisableCommits is 
      begin
          update tbl_block_unwanted_commits set nest_counter = nest_counter +1;
          if sql%notfound then
             insert into tbl_block_unwanted_commits(only_one_row,nest_counter)
             values ('X',1);
          end if;
      end;

      procedure ReenableCommits is
      begin
         update tbl_block_unwanted_commits set nest_counter = nest_counter -1;
      end;
  end;
  /
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'll up-vote the ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE answer above.  But, as it's been pointed out -- that doesn't work if you are already in a transaction.  That is, you are in a situation where you intend to commit, but you don't want a called procedure to commit before you are ready.

What I do in this situation is write something to detect that a COMMIT has happened.  It doesn't prevent the commit, but it causes an error in my program -- even if the commit doesn't hurt anything.

This way, I am 100% sure to detect during testing that the COMMIT is happening and can deal with it in design.

Here's a link to a description of the approach I am describing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31752576/5174436